chown cannot dereference, Permission denied
Given,
touch /tmp/abc
ln -vs abc /tmp/def

$ ls -l /tmp/???
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Apr 10 22:10 /tmp/abc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3 Apr 10 22:10 /tmp/def -> abc

Why I'm getting:
$ sudo chown syslog: /tmp/def
chown: cannot dereference '/tmp/def': Permission denied

$ sudo chown --dereference syslog: /tmp/def
chown: cannot dereference '/tmp/def': Permission denied

Ref: 
chown(1):

--dereference
affect  the  referent  of each symbolic link
(this is the default), rather than the
symbolic link itself

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal


I think this is a consequence of fs.protected_symlinks = 1 in combination with the sticky bit on /tmp

What happens if you do sudo chown syslog: /tmp/abc?  What happens if you leave out the :?  Also, please try ls -lL /tmp/def.

This answer supposes that this is in place:
# sysctl fs.protected_symlinks 
fs.protected_symlinks = 1


The root user (which the following security feature was especially intended to affect) as any other users, is affected by the sysctl fs.protected_symlinks described in proc(5):

/proc/sys/fs/protected_symlinks (since Linux 3.6)
When the value in this file is 0, no restrictions are
placed on following symbolic links (i.e., this is the
historical behavior before Linux 3.6).  When the value in
this file is 1, symbolic links are followed only in the
following circumstances:
•  the filesystem UID of the process following the link
matches the owner (UID) of the symbolic link (as
described in credentials(7), a process's filesystem UID
is normally the same as its effective UID);
•  the link is not in a sticky world-writable directory;
or
•  the symbolic link and its parent directory have the
same owner (UID)
A system call that fails to follow a symbolic link because
of the above restrictions returns the error EACCES in
errno.

Here:

root !=  ubuntu : fail
/tmp is a sticky world-writable directory: fail
def's owner (ubuntu) is not the same as /tmp's owner (root): fail

hence EACCESS = Permission denied
Here are two other cases that would work instead:

prevent first condition to fail
sudo chown --no-dereference root: /tmp/def # this must be root, not syslog

Now the symbolic link is owned by root the 1st condition won't fail, allowing then to run:
 sudo chown syslog: /tmp/def

To successfully affect /tmp/abc.
If so intended, def can be changed back to its previous owner or to syslog too:
sudo chown --no-dereference ubuntu: /tmp/def

or
sudo chown --no-dereference syslog: /tmp/def


Prevent 2nd condition to fail
Do the same experiment in a non-sticky directory (even if it is world-writable):
sudo mkdir -m 777 /tmp/notsticky
sudo mv /tmp/abc /tmp/def /tmp/notsticky/.

Which now allows to run:
sudo chown syslog: /tmp/notsticky/def

They can be moved back if that's the intention:
sudo mv /tmp/notsticky/abc /tmp/notsticky/def /tmp/
sudo rmdir /tmp/notsticky




In addition, as suggested in comment , one can again prevent the first condition to fail by doing the lookup from the original ubuntu user, since it's already the owner of the symbolic link. For example using:
realpath -z /tmp/def | xargs -0 sudo chown syslog:

or if there's no special character such as a Line Feed (LF / \n) at the end of the target filename (which would be removed by the shell interpreter), as in OP's case, simply:
sudo chown syslog: "$(realpath /tmp/def)"


I guess you could also (as owner of the symlink) do sudo chown syslog: "$(realpath /tmp/def)" so that link traversal is done by the owner's process

Thanks for the most comprehensive answer. Yep, I followed them step by step and was able to overcome the problems. BTW, what I'm trying to do is to change the owner of the linked file, so @steeldriver's above solution seems to be the easiest one for me. Thank you both!

BTW, for fs.protected_symlinks, which "The root user .. was especially intended to be affected", is an overkill IMHO, as "affect the referent of each symbolic link" is the default behaviour, that everyone knowing sudo should know as well. I would sudo sysctl fs.protected_symlinks=0 next time if I bumped into it again.

@xpt I insisted on the root user because people would argue that root should be exempted because it's root, when that's the one that is the most at risk. Also instead I would use: mktemp -d and work in this subdirectory. This guarantees to pass the 2nd bullet. Same kind of issue (but a different sysfs) when using tcpdump which alters its own uid: it can't write twice the same file in /tmp, but can in /tmp/subdir .
